# Кто как реализует поддержку многоязычности на сайте?

Tags: php

Сейчас все построено на созданных полях в базе, соответствующие языку, например:
TITLE, TITLE_EN, TITLE_RU
Но с ростом таблиц и языков - администрирование становится невозможным.

Comment: Tut nawel reweniya, no oni toje realizovamiȘ http://hashcode.ru/questions/11793/php-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82
Neujeli takie saiti kak odnoklassniki, ispolizuiut takie metodi?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, одноклассники могут себе позволить использовать худшие на свете решения. Но вообще всегда интернационализация сводится к тому, что определяется текущий язык, а потом грузится массив переведенных строк. Можно применять еще .po/.mo фалйы, в них удобнее вести интернационализацию, но не сказать, что подход принципиально отличается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну подход в моей фирме особо не отличается от подходов [@ICE](/users/2587/ice) и [@Fike](/users/16095/fike). Он более унифицированный, так как эта система одинаково применяется во всех продуктах компании от собственной cms на php и порталов asp.net до десктоп и мобильных приложений на delphi.

- Язык системы хранится в сессии
- Существует некий xml-файл, в котором объявляются языки системы, хранятся переводы всех фраз, которые нужно переводить, информация для версионности и пр. . Примерно в таком  формате, к примеру, объявляются языки:

  ```
  <Languages>
  <Language>
      <ID type="string" nil="False">DEFAULT</ID>
      <InternationalName type="string" nil="False">Russian</InternationalName>
      <OwnerName type="string" nil="False">Русский</OwnerName>
  </Language>
  <Language>
      <ID type="string" nil="False">KAZ</ID>
      <InternationalName type="string" nil="False">Kazakh</InternationalName>
      <OwnerName type="string" nil="False">Қазақша</OwnerName>
  </Language>
  ```

  </Languages>

Сам перевод в таком формате:

```
<word id="0x00000001">
<DEFAULT type="string" nil="False">Наличие котлов, шт</DEFAULT>
<KAZ type="string" nil="False">Қазандар саны, дана </KAZ>
</word>
```

Благодаря файлу достигается любое кол-во поддерживаемых локализаций и все переводы хранятся в одном месте.

- Для заполнения файла фразами написан модуль, который пробегается по всему исходному коду и добавляет в xml. Фразы помечаются особым образом. Мы берем в символы двойного процента: %%какая-нибудь фраза%%. При запуске какой-нибудь страницы сначала запускается парсер, все фразы в %% %% заменяет на нужный язык и юзеру уже отдается траница на его языке.
- Для заполнения файла переводами написана десктопная программка, удобная для штатных переводчиков. Они уже продуктивно работают с xml-файлом, отвязаны от бд (могут работать дома, можем просто перевод отдать на аутсорс) и им дела нет, для чего нужен этот перевод. При выходе новой версии перевода на сервере заменяется xml-файл, никаких изменений кода не требуется в принципе.
- Статьи же или тексты большого размера храним в бд с разными полями для языков, либо языки выносим в отдельную таблицу - если не уверены, что кол-во языков останется постоянным. Здесь уже в принципе ничего страшного и нет

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то, в решении такой же проблемы, очень помогла статья - http://habrahabr.ru/post/115300/